# How can overwrite the branch from another branch in git

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I had `feature` branch and then `master` branch.

I made copy of `feature` to `feature1` and master copy to `master1`

Then i

```
git checkout master1
git merge feature1
# Resolved all conflicts and commited
```

Then i went

```
git checkout master
git rebase master1
```

Then i did 1 more commit on master to fix the things

Now i have master branch as i like but i can't push it. 
so ideally i want to have this new master branch code on my previous `feature` branch

so that my all previous commits are there as well and i can continue commiting like before

[image]

SO in the picture top `42bb` is my master `HEAD`

and  bottom `161a` is my feature branch.

I want my feature branch `HEAD` to be `42bb` or may be a new commit on feature branch which is equal to `42bb` commit

I did this but was not sure if that was right

`git reset --hard master` on my feature branch

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, but possibly manually calling `git commit-tree` will do what you want - if what you want is to create a new commit on feature that has a tree that looks like master.

Comment: @AndrewC basically my master branch is 2 commits ahead of feature where first commit is merge commit and 2 is my manual commit. Now i want feature branch to have a commit which is combination of both merge commit and manual commit. so that if i need to merge with master again i don't need to fix the conflicts. I have added the graph in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my feature branch HEAD to be 42bb

```
git checkout feature 
# standard warning about reset --hard being working directory unsafe 
git reset --hard HEAD
```

> may be a new commit on feature branch which is equal to 42bb commit

This one is a little more complex.

```
git commit-tree -p feature -m "commit msg" 42bb^{tree}
```

That will create a commit parented by  161a with the tree contents of 42bb. 
You'd need to update feature branch to point to the returned SHA with `git update-ref`

Comment: That first one you can also do with `git checkout -B feature 42bb`.  If `feature` isn't checked out already, `git branch -f feature 42bb` will avoid checking it out, sometimes that's a good thing. Yay for commit-tree :-)